# Effective strategy for writing functions as turing machine flow charts

Tags: recursion, turing-machines

I've been having trouble in visualizing functions as turing machines and vice versa. Is there a way of thinking that I can use to do this kind of conversion/visualization? Or do you have to be smart and suddenly "get the entire thing"?

For example, how could you write a turing machine for the function f(x1,x2,...,xn) = x1+x2+...+xn?

I can do this with a simple recursion in any programming languages I know. But I still can't tie it into a turing machine.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use Brainfuck, but any Brainfuck program can be transformed to a universal turing machine program.

As for the example you have, the simplest program to do what you want is this:

```
>[<[->+<]>>]
```

So imagine you have the following state:

```
1 2 3 4 5 0 ...
^
```

After the program has halted you will have the following state

```
0 0 0 0 15 0 ...
           ^
```

If you open [the visualizer](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#Kz4rKz4rKys+KysrKz4rKysrKzw8PDwgc2V0dXAKPls8Wy0+KzxdPj5d) it's pretty easy to see what is happening.

Here is the same program in a Universal turing machine:

```
;; Adds the input together in hexadecimal
;; This does the same as BF >[<[->+<]>>]

; initial state go to check
0 * * r c ; >

; check if done
c 0 0 * halt ; [...] (when _)
c * * l r    ; [< (otherwise)

; r(educe) here, then i(ncrease) except when 0
r 0 0 r n    ; []> (when 0)
r 1 0 r i    ; [-> (when 1)
i 0 1 l r    ; +<] (when 0)
r 2 1 r i    ; [-> (when 2)
i 1 2 l r    ; +<] (when 1)
r 3 2 r i    ; etc.
i 2 3 l r
r 4 3 r i
i 3 4 l r
r 5 4 r i
i 4 5 l r
r 6 5 r i
i 5 6 l r
r 7 6 r i
i 6 7 l r
r 8 7 r i
i 7 8 l r
r 9 8 r i
i 8 9 l r
r A 9 r i
i 9 A l r
r B A r i
i A B l r
r C B r i
i B C l r
r D C r i
i C D l r
r E D r i
i D E l r
r F E r i
i E F l r


; go to right check if done
n * * r c     ; >
```

You need to have 123450 as the initial tape and I have done so in [an online simulator](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?6c3cb1d5c415bd22405983b557272149). Now the reason this is much longer than the BF version is that a turing machine doesn't have the concept of numbers, only symbols. I'll have to tell it what the successor of each digit is and what the predecessor for each digit is. It also means I get to decide how to model my numbers and as you see I opted for hex since the visualizer has problems with more than one char symbols. (with limitations like these no wonder we're not all programming in it :-) )

Now while the turing machine example would break for number higher than 15 the BreanFuck version has only guaranteed 256 states per cell. Thus to make a program to add arbitrarily large numbers you'd need a way to model numbers even in BF. For turing machines it's the possibility to calculate which is the point of the excercise and how hard it is to present input and output and model data is just details. I have made [a lisp interpreter](https://github.com/westerp/zozotez) in BF and I've seen some [fancy BF programs](http://www.hevanet.com/cristofd/brainfuck/) outputting large calculated numbers. Thus it's usually the limitation of our imagination and not the turing machines fault that a) the program is not possible b) the program has low elegance.